# remove <text>-tag from output while writing file with vfs

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i want to write a file with the payload as csv(as plan taxt) in an sequence.
My problem is that i always get the <**text** xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">-tag surrounding my data.

Can anybody help my removing this tag?

Result:

```
    <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">HALLO 13,hallo 11,hallo 12,hallo 11hallo 12
HALLO 23,hallo 21,hallo 22,hallo 21hallo 22
HALLO 33,hallo 31,hallo 32,hallo 31hallo 32</text>
```

Sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="fileWriteSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property expression="fn:concat( get-property('NewFileName'), '.', get-property('NewFileFormat'))" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2-client" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/> 
    <send>
        <endpoint name="FileEpr">
            <address format="pox" uri="vfs:file:///C:/WSO2/ESB/VFS/OUTPUT/"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was working fine for old releases of WSO2 products and we also faced the same issue with WSO2 EI 6.3.0 and 6.2.0 versions.

It seems WSO2 did a change on message formatter direction logic since `format="pox"` is defined in the endpoint level. It's Ignoring the `messageType` property in newer releases. Therefore you have to remove endpoint format configuration from your address endpoint.

So you need to change your logic as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="fileWriteSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">

    <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
    <property expression="fn:concat( get-property('NewFileName'), '.', get-property('NewFileFormat'))" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint name="FileEpr">
            <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/WSO2/ESB/VFS/OUTPUT/"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working now.
Not sure if this was the only thing i had to change, because i tried a lot more.
But finally it's working now! Thanks